# How to perform breusch-pagan test in statsmodels?

Tags: python, statistics, data-science, data-analysis, statsmodels

I want to use breusch_pagan test in statsmodels, but i facea strange error:

```
print(het_breuschpagan(resid=lr.resid,exog_het=df['iq']))
  File "C:\Users\aleks\PycharmProjects\statistics\venv\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\stats\diagnostic.py", line 810, in het_breuschpagan
    nobs, nvars = x.shape
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

linear model:

```
lr = sm.OLS.from_formula('lw80~age80+iq+school80+expr80',df).fit()
```

Dataset:

```
  rns rns80  mrt mrt80 smsa  ...  expr80  tenure  tenure80     lw   lw80
0  no    no   no   yes  yes  ...  10.635       0         2  5.900  6.645
1  no    no   no   yes  yes  ...  11.367       2        16  5.438  6.694
2  no    no   no   yes  yes  ...  11.035       1         9  5.710  6.715
3  no    no   no   yes  yes  ...  13.089       1         7  5.481  6.477
4  no    no  yes   yes  yes  ...  14.402       3         5  5.927  6.332
```

I would like to test wether there is a heteroskadicity assuming that the variable leading to heteroskadicity is iq and only iq, but I don't know what parameters to use so that there are no errors

Comment: I suspect that `exog_het` needs to be 2d.  Try `df[['iq']]`.

Comment: For the BP test to be well specified, you need to have at least 2 columns where 1 contains a constant. That sm doesn't check is a bug, and the [fix is here](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/pull/8130).

Answer (score 0):

The bresuschpagan implementation in statsmodel compares the residuals to the X dataset used in your ols regression, so that would be

```
het_breuschpagan(resid=lr.resid, exog_het=df[['age80','iq','school80','expr80']])
```